# How and What to edit in httpd.conf?

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I am a newbie in PHP and the Apache server things. All I want is to run and test my PHP scripts on my computer i.e a single computer environment.

I installed the Apache HTTP Server 2.2.25 on my Windows 8 OS (64 bit). I installed PHP 5 through IIS Web Platform Installer.
During the server installation I set the network and server to `localhost`.

I created this file txt.php and tried localhost/txt.php but the browser shows nothing.

What's missing?

I heard we have to edit the httpd.conf file, if yes then what and how to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing Apache HTTP Server (wich is a http server) and PHP5 on a IIS (Wich is an http server for windows)

One of the easiest way to have a server up and running in windows is through http://www.wampserver.com/en/

So, uninstall all you installed on your question and use Wamp to manage the server with PHP and Mysql runing without more problems.

Of course, you can install all by your own, but since you want just a server runing, this one will help you to start fast.

Wamp lets you control the software versions, so you can try different php versions, apache versions, etc.